# Why assignment operator chain process in right to left order

Tags: java

Why are assignment chains are evaluated in right to left order?

```
i = j = k = 10;
```

is

```
k = 10;
j = k;
i = j;
```

Addition is evaluated left to right:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int i = m1() + m2() + m3();
}

public static int m1()
{
    System.out.println("m1");
    return 1;
}
public static int m2()
{
    System.out.println("m2");
    return 2;
}
public static int m3()
{
    System.out.println("m3");
    return 3;
}
```

Output:

```
m1
m2
m3
```

According to which rule are assignment operator chains processed in right to left order?

Comment: `int j = m1()=m2()=m3();` is not valid. The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable.

Comment: `i=j=k=10` is executed like `i=(j=(k=10))` - here value assigned is also *returned* by expression so `k=10` also returns that 10 which allows us to assign it again in `j` and then in `i`. How else would you suggest to execute it?

Answer (score 1):

Why?  Because that's the most useful order, and seems to conform to most people's expectations, perhaps in part because that's the usual case.

The other way round would be surprising (i.e., a source of bugs):

```
int k;
j = 42;
i = j = k = 10;
```

Left to right leaves i at 42, j undefined, and k 10.  Right to left makes all 3 variables have the value 10, much more useful.

Which rule?  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26

Answer (score 0):

Chainable assignment is right-associative (i.e. right to left) simply because that is the only way it would make sense. The operation `i = j = k = 10` is supposed to assign 10 to all three variables. If it was done left to right, it would evaluate to

```
i = j;
j = k;
k = 10;
```

Rather, than assigning the same value to all three, it would be "shifting" the values: `i` gets the old value of `j`, `j` gets the old value of `k`, and only `k` gets the value 10. Now, this could possibly be a useful operation to have, but it is not the intended behaviour here, so it has to be done from right to left.

Also, going left to right would evaluate to `((i = j) = k) = 10`, which would be putting an rvalue (the assignment expression as a whole is an rvalue) on the left side of an assignment, which is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

The evaluation order is specified in the [Java Language Specification (JLS)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/jls13.pdf). In section `15.26 Assignment Operators` is written

> There are 12 assignment operators; all are syntactically right-associative (they
>   group right-to-left). Thus, a=b=c means a=(b=c), which assigns the value of c to
>   b and then assigns the value of b to a.

This means, that the right-most assignment is performed first, then then next to the left etc.

Generally, the precedence of operations is specified by the grammar of Java. This also specifies why additions are performed after multiplications.

Concerning you first question: It would be quite counter-intuitive to evaluate the assignment in a different order, as the variables could have different values afterwards.